# non-static method Issue

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, instance

I know there is a lot of post of this problem, i've read a lot of them but I can't resolve mine.
I'll try to ask the question in the best way possible so that not too much trouble.

Well, I have two JPanels, and i want to get one the JPanel (JCatalog) displayed in the application to modify it from the other JPanel (JPanelTicket).

Now when I call the method getComponent of JCatalog, it shows me the `non-static method can't be referenced from a static context`.
I'd try everything I know and I search a lot but I dont know how to solve this.

This is my source code:

JCatalog:

```
package newpackage;
import java.awt.Component;

public class JCatalog extends javax.swing.JPanel {


    public JCatalog() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public Component getComponent() {
        return this;
    }
```

JPanelTicket:

```
package javaapplication5;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import newpackage.JCatalog;


public abstract class JPanelTicket extends JPanel {

    JCatalog jcat;

    public JPanelTicket() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void init(){
        jcat = (JCatalog) JCatalog.getComponent(); //Here's the problem
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do? getComponent is a non-static method. So you need a object to call it. `jcat = (JCatalog) JCatalog.getComponent();` is wrong. You need a JCatalog object.

Comment: *"i've read a lot of them"*  Really?  Link to the 5 that were closest to your query, & explain in what way they failed to answer it..

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/615326/java/java/Calling-method-JPanel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a non-static method using class, like `JCatalog.getComponent()`

A non-static method can only be called with instance `jcat.getComponent()`

I see that you have an reference maintained of type `JCatalog` named `jcat`. Make sure you **initialize** it somewhere OR set the instance using *setter method*. And use this instance to call the `getComponent()` method

```
public abstract class JPanelTicket extends JPanel {

    JCatalog jcat;

    public JPanelTicket() {
        jcat = new JCatalog();
        initComponents();
    }

    public void init(){
        jcat = jcat.getComponent(); //Here's the problem
    }
}
```

OR

```
public abstract class JPanelTicket extends JPanel {

    JCatalog jcat;

    public JPanelTicket() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void init(){
        jcat = jcat.getComponent(); //Here's the problem
    }

    public void setJCatalog(JCatalog jcat) {
        this.jcat = jcat;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if I do something like `JCatalog jcat = new JCatalog()` and then `JCatalog jcat2 = (JCatalog) jcat.getComponent();` It will get the instance of the JCatalog displayed?

Comment: yes it should work.. but make sure you are working with **right instance** of `JCatalog`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you solve it:

```
public class JCatalog extends javax.swing.JPanel {
  private static Component INSTANCE;

  public JCatalog() {
      initComponents();
      INSTANCE = this;
  }

  public static Component getComponent() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
```

This will work under the assumption that your `JCatalog` is a *singleton*, which means you only create one instance in your application.

Comment: I'd read about this too, but didn't know how to implement it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling `JCatalog.getComponent();` You're calling a non-static method in a static way.
Static means that you don't have to instantiate your object in order to call the method.

When you type `JCatalog.getComponent();` your `JCatalog' isn't instantiated yet.

```
JCatalog jCatalogObj = new JCatalog();
jcat = jCatalogObj.getComponent();
```

This way you'll be calling it in a non-static way because you create a new instance of your `JCatalog` first before calling it's method.

But if you're going to return `this` in the method, you might just want to do this:

```
jcat = new JCatalog();
```

**So I would rewrite your code like this:**

```
package javaapplication5;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import newpackage.JCatalog;

public abstract class JPanelTicket extends JPanel {

    JCatalog jcat;

    public JPanelTicket() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void init(){
        jcat = new JCatalog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getComponent` method is non-static and you are trying to refer it in static style

you need a reference object to invoke `getComponent` method

You can try like this :

```
public void init(){
        jcat = new JCatalog().getComponent(); //Here's the problem
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of JCatalog to access its methods. Your static way of accessing non-static would not work.

```
   public void init(){
       JCatalog jcat = new JCatalog();
       jcat.getComponent();
   }
```